# How to use Nav2, slam_toolbox with odom data, gps and imu sensors?

Tags: slam, gps, ros2, nav2

**Setup details**: ROS2 foxy on amd64 architecture CPU with nav2 and slam_toolbox installed

Robot is Clearpath husky with Velodyne VLP-16 lidar, IMU and GPS sensor in gazebo. Can see data on every topic

**Long term Objective**: Provide gps co-ordinates as goal / way points and autonomously navigate robot to the destination with the help of Nav2 stack by using slam_toolbox

**Short term objective**: Obtain a stable map (drift free)/ no shaking behavior (if that's possible) using slam_toolbox which updates when obstacles are removed from environment.

Below are the topics. Sometimes `/odometry/local` is present, sometimes not even though the node is running through launch file. Also, `ros2 node list` does not show anything which seems weird to me. But in another round, it works (surprised, seems like some foxy bug to me)

```
/clock
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/downsampled_costmap
/downsampled_costmap_updates
/e_stop
/global_costmap/costmap
/global_costmap/costmap_updates
/goal_pose
/gps/data
/gps/filtered
/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel_unstamped
/imu/data
/initialpose
/joint_states
/joy_teleop/cmd_vel
/map
/map_updates
/odom
/odometry/global
/odometry/gps
/parameter_events
/plan
/robot_description
/rosout
/scan
/tf
/tf_static
/twist_marker_server/cmd_vel
/velodyne_points
/waypoints
```

My workflow is as below.

1. Spawn the robot in gazebo, all the sensors are outputting data.
2. Run `ros2 launch pointcloud_to_laserscan sample_pointcloud_to_laserscan_launch.py` to convert 3D point cloud to 2D laserscan on `/scan` topic which can be used later on by slam_toolbox
3. Since the odometry information (from topic `/odom` from wheel encoders) is know to have drift in real life, its good to use EKF to fuse odometry data from other sensors (IMU and GPS). There are 4 scenarios/ combinations described down in the post and this is how I am calling the nodes in the launch file (`control.launch.py` present at the google drive link (had to finally upload as could not represent the code in code view)). I just comment `ld.add_action(node_ekf_local)` if I don't want to run the `ekf_filter_node_odom` as an example and so on.

Content of the yaml configuration file provided by `config_husky_ekf` are provided by `localization.yaml` present at the google drive path which contains configuration for three nodes: ekf_filter_node_map (or global), ekf_filter_node_odom (or local), and navsat_transform_node (to convert gps co-ordinates to odometry data)

I then tried 4 scenarios: Configs and videos of all 4 are present here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16_x99OUOEJZVyFfYeAMvAYkP9elPXNxH?usp=sharing

`1_no_ekf_original_odom_only_slam_toolbox_TF_yes_robot_OKayish_but_map-no_update`: EKF node is not running (no sensor fusion), original `/odom` data is used; slam_toolbox is publishing the map frame, `/map` topic and the related tf. Robot motion seems okayish to me because there is still little bit of drift between the map and 2d laserscan/ 3d pointcloud showing obstacles when the robot rotates. When an obstacle is removed from gazebo, the map does not update in rviz.

`2_ekf_local_only_slam_toolbox_TF_yes_robot_OKayish_but_map-no_update`: EKF node is running but fusing only `odom` and `imu` data i.e. local one and publishing `odom` to `base_link` transform. slam_toolbox is publishing the map frame, `/map` topic and the related tf. Robot motion seems okayish to me because there is still little bit of drift between the map and 2d laserscan/ 3d pointcloud showing obstacles when the robot rotates. When an obstacle is removed from gazebo, the map does not update in rviz.

`3_ekf_local_global_slam_toolbox_TF_yes_robot_going_coming_after_motion`: EKF node is running but this time both local (fusing odom and imu) and global (odom, imu and gps odometry (on the topic `/odometry/gps`) are running. Since, the ekf_filter_node_map (global one) is running, `/map` frame and its related tf is present this time. Run slam_toolbox using the default setting `transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry` which messes up the story because two nodes (`ekf_filter_node_map` and the one by `slam_toolbox`) are publishing different tfs for the same frames which is shown by erratic behavior in rviz. Although the same is not visible in tf2_echo probably because of the less frequency at which it is showing the TFs.

`4_ekf_local_global_slam_toolbox_no_TF_robot_gone_after_motion`: In order to avoid the issue observed in #3, I set `transform_publish_period: 0.0 #if 0 never publishes odometry; The map to odom transform publish period. 0 will not publish transforms`. Now, Both EKF nodes (local and global) are running. Since, the ekf_filter_node_map (global one) is running, `/map` frame and its related tf is present this time as well. As soon as slam_toolbox is ran, shaky behavior is observed no more (such a relief but not for too long!!!) The map is not aligned with the obstacles and as robot starts to move, robot vanishes from the display because the tf's translation between map and odom frames becomes a very large number.

I think the third approach should be the best but it has some issues which I described earlier. I tried tuning the parameters a lot but of no use. Please suggest the best way to achieve the stated objectives and tell if the long term objective is contradictory with the short term. Thanks a lot in advance.